# Replace implementation of instantiated class without touching the code (java)

Tags: java, unit-testing, constructor, dependency-injection, classloader

I have legacy code I don't want to touch.

```
public class LegacyCode{
    public LegacyCode() {
        Service s = new ClassA();
        s.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Where `ClassA` provides a CORBA service call.

```
public class ClassA implements Service{
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
       // Make CORBA service call...
       return "Class A";
    }
}
```

And the interface `Service` looks like;

```
public interface Service {
    String getMessage();
}
```

For test purposes, I want to replace the implementation of `Service` (in `LegacyCode` implemented by `ClassA`) with a stub.

```
public class ClassB implements Service {
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return "Stub Class B";
    }
}
```

So far so good. But is it possible without any modifications at the shown legacy code to load `ClassB` instead of `ClassA` at the instantiation of `ClassA`?

```
// In my test workbench
new LegacyCode(); // "Stub Class B"
```

I've tried to write a custom classloader and load it at application start by java vm arguments but only the first class (here `LegacyCode`) was loaded by that loader.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Best would be to use dependency injection from the start. Then these issues would be moot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunatelly the existing code (many classes) doesn't provide this feature at the moment. We don't want to make these mondifications without new business requirements. But we need to test the code without the CORBA call.

Comment: Is this for a unit-test if that is so, you can do it with power-mock. Let me know if that's the case and I'll explain how.

Answer (score 3):

Using `PowerMock` you can create a mock (or stub) for a constructor code. The answer is taken from [this link](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor). I'll try to convert it to match exactly to your use case:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ClassA.class)
public class LegacyTester {
    @Test
    public void testService() {
         // Inject your stub
         PowerMock.createMock(ClassA.class);
         Service stub = new MyServiceStub();
         PowerMock.expectNew(ClassA.class).andReturn(stub);
         PowerMock.replay(stub, ClassA.class);

         // Implement test logic here

         LegacyCode legacyCode = new LegacyCode();

         // Implement Test steps

        // Call verify if you want to make sure the ClassA constructor was called
        PowerMock.verify(stub, ClassA.class)
    }
}
```

This way you inject your stub when the call to `ClassA` constructor happens, without changing the legacy code. Hope that's what you needed.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with AspectJ.  I agree with Hovercraft, this is a good case for dependency injection but if you can't change the source code, AspectJ might be your tool of choice.

This explains the AspectJ case better than I can: [Can AspectJ replace "new X" with "new SubclassOfX" in third-party library code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16355771/can-aspectj-replace-new-x-with-new-subclassofx-in-third-party-library-code)

Answer (score 0):

The easier thing to do is to just create a `ClassA` in your test code. Declare it in the same package originally found in the actual code and use the same method names. Just make the method do nothing.

For example, if your project structure looks like this:

```
+- src
  +- main
    +- java
      +- com.company.code
        -- LegacyCode.java
        -- Service.java
      +- com.company.code.service
        -- ClassA.java
  +- test
    +- java
      +- com.company.code
        -- LegacyCodeTest.java
```

Create an alternative `ClassA` under `/src/test/java/com/company/code/`:

```
package com.company.code.service;
/** Replaces the original implementation for testing purposes */
public class ClassA implements Service{
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
       return "I replaced the original implementation";
    }
}
```

Now your project structure will look like this:

```
+- src
  +- main
    +- java
      +- com.company.code
        -- LegacyCode.java
        -- Service.java
      +- com.company.code.service
        -- ClassA.java
  +- test
    +- java
      +- com.company.code
        -- LegacyCodeTest.java
      +- com.company.code.service
        -- ClassA.java
```

When your unit tests execute, the `ClassA` from your `test` folder will be loaded. This is way simpler than using a mock framework especially if your old code is messy, not dependency-injection-friendly and the actual `ClassA` is used everywhere.

Just keep in mind that this sort of strategy can make your test code a bit more obscure, and you can't test the actual implementation of `ClassA` itself, nor easily provide alternative implementations for different test scenarios.

Comment: Is this approach called stubbing? How JUnit replaces actual class with the test implementation