# mock a method call with dynamic parameter

Tags: junit, junit4, easymock, powermock

I have a method as follows

```
private void validate(String schemaName){
    ....
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);**strong text**
    Source schemaFile = new SteamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaName));
    Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    ....
}
```

This method get called from another method which I need to test(Using easymock and powermock). I'm struggling to mock following line

```
Source schemaFile = new SteamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaName));
```

Can someone give me a clue on this?

Current Status

Following is the mock statement

```
expectNew(StreamSource.class, anyObject(InputStream.class)).andReturn(mockedobject); 

Powermock.replay(mockedobject, StreamSrouce.class);
```

This throws the following exception.

```
org.powermock.reflect.exceptions.TooManyConstructorsFoundException: Several matching constructors found, please specify the argument parameter types so that PowerMock can determine which method you're referring to. 
Matching constructors in class javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource were:
```

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Please guid me.

Comment: @K.Senthuran - I added an answer. Really hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Aside for my original question, it was suggested to use constructor mock which is also a possibility. You can have a look at my answer on another question on how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307121/replace-implementation-of-instantiated-class-without-to-touch-code-java/19308216#19308216

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it using `powermock` in the following way (I'm just following the tutorial [here](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockPartial)):

Let's say you're class looks like this:

```
public class MyClass {
   private void validate(String schemaName) {
   ....
   SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);**strong text**
   Source schemaFile = new SteamSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaName));
   Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaFile);
....
   }
}
```

You should create a test class like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class) 
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class) 
public class MyClassTest {

   private MyClass testedClass = new MyClass();
   private ClassLoader mockedClassLoader = createMock(ClassLoader.class);
   private InputStream mockedInputStream = createMock(InputStream.class);

   @Before
   public void setUp() {
       PowerMock.createPartialMock(MyClass.class, "getClass");
       expect(testedClass.getClass()).andReturn(mockedClassLoader);
       expected(mockedClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(***You string***)).andReturn(mockedInputStream);
       replayAll(); // Not sure if that's the name of the method - you need to call replay on all mocks
   }


   @Test
   public void testValidate() {
       // Run your test logic here
   }
}
```

Please excuse me if some of the `easymock` methods I used are named a bit differently. But this is the basic idea.

Comment: This seems like overkill. Just mock the constructor call.

Comment: I tried this Avi with some changes. I have to use expect call like "EasyMock.expect(....)" then 2nd line of the setUp method I had to change is like "EasyMock.expect(testedClass.getClass().getClassLoader()).andReturn(mockedClassLoader);". 3rd line I think you ment expect again. 

But I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: no last call on a mock available" exception from line 2 of setup method.

Comment: @susithasenarath Have you put the `PrepareForTest` annotation on top of the class with the mocked class? It's important

Comment: @Avi can you pls explain the lines inside setUp method?

Comment: @susithasenarath - the idea is to mock only part of the class (because most of the class you want to test). First line defines the method to mock, second line defines what happens when calling `getClass()` which is - return a mocked class loader instead of the original one. Then you do the same on the mocked class loader and return a mocked `InputStream`. The replay records the actions.
No you can run your test and mock the line you wanted.

Comment: BTW - the solution of John B is good as well. I put a link on the question comment explaining how to do it (I answered it in another question already).

Comment: @Avi 
I'm trying your suggetion again. Help me to fix this.

PowerMock.createPartialMock(MyClass.class, "getClass");
expect(testedClass.getClass()).andReturn(mockedClassLoader);

We are returning a classloader for a getclass method. This is wrong isn't it?

Comment: That's what you need to do. What's the problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need one or a combination of the following. Use `Powermock` constructor mocking for the `new StreamSource` as documented [here: Powermock MockConstructor](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor). You will probably also need to use a mock for `SchemaFactory` which mean you will need to mock the static factory method call via [Powermock: MockStatic](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic)

Comment: I start like this
Source mockSource = createMock(Source.class)
expectNew(Source.class, InputStream.clas);

since "getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(schemaName)" return a InputStream I put parameter as InputStream class. Is this correct?

Comment: Not working. just replayAll() should initiate the mock isn't it. I have both easymock and Powermock statements.

Comment: First thing to do is choose one. You are making your life more complicated by using both at the same time.

Comment: Powermock contain easymock too isn't it?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Powermock can do all the same type of mocking that Easymock can do so there is not a reason to use both at the same time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39281/discussion-between-susitha-senarath-and-john-b)