# How to replace implementation of interface without changing code?

Tags: c++, interface

Suppose I wrote some code like this:

```
// myinterface.h
struct MyInterface { void foo()=0; };

// mydefault.h
#include "myinterface.h"
struct MyDefaultImplementation : MyInterface { void foo(){} };

// main.cpp
#include "myinterface.h"
#include "mydefault.h"    // (X)
int main(){
    MyInterface* x = new MyDefaultImplementation();  // (X)
    x->foo();
}
```

I can provide a different implementation of the interface easily, but I need to change the lines where I create the instance and of course the include (X).

**Is it possible to replace the implementation of the interface without changing existing code?**

Just to clarify: of course with the above code it is not possible, but can I change it somehow, such that later when I want to switch to another implementation of the interface I dont have to change it?

The closest I could find is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19307121/replace-implementation-of-instantiated-class-without-to-touch-code-java), but thats java :(

Btw the example is very much simplified, but also in my actual code, there is only a single line in the code, where I create the instance.

Comment: *Is it possible to replace the implementation of the interface without changing existing code?* I don't see how you can do that. You have to change existing code somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a factory approach, eg:

myinterface.h

```
struct MyInterface
{
    virtual ~MyInterface() {}
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

MyInterface* createMyInterface();
```

main.cpp

```
#include "myinterface.h"

int main()
{
    MyInterface* x = createMyInterface();
    x->foo();
    delete x;
}
```

Then you can make `createMyInterface()` create whatever struct type you need, eg:

mydefault.h

```
#include "myinterface.h"

struct MyDefaultImplementation : MyInterface
{
    void foo(){}
};
```

myinterface.cpp

```
#include "mydefault.h"

MyInterface* createMyInterface()
{
    return new MyDefaultImplementation;
}
```

Comment: well, I was almost expecting that it is going in this direction. However, this just shifts the need to change code from anywhere else to the factory function. I still would need to change myinterface.cpp. In my particular case, where the creation of the instance is already confined to a single line, I wouldnt gain much, right?

Comment: If you want the struct type fixed at compile-time, you are going to have to make a code change *somewhere* in order to specify which struct type to instantiate.  Otherwise, you will have to make it dynamic instead, where you register multiple class types in a private list, and then have the factory function decide which entry to return based on some input value that is provided at run-time.

Comment: I want to use only a single type, but that type might change in the future. I think in my example the changes that have to be done to switch to a different implemenation are already minimal, I just wasnt sure if there exists some magic that I am not aware of. I will accept your answer, but I would be happy, if you could add a line saying something like: "No you cant do it without changing any code. The best way to go is to use a factory approach [because in genral the creation of the instances is not confined to a single line in your code, and thats what you gain by using a factory]"

Comment: Rather than changing the one line that instantiates the actual object, why not just change the actual implementation of `MyDefaultImplementation` itself when needed?  Are you planning on compiling multiple implementation types? If so, you might need to `#ifdef` your code to make different decisions at compile-time.

Comment: the implementation of the interface is supposed to be provided by users (or myself) depending on the use case and I dont want to manage different versions of some default implementation and also I love the way interfaces can guide you to get stuff implemented quickly (guess what, yes I have some java background ;)

Comment: If you let the user provide the implementation, then either the user has to change your implementation code statically at compile-time, or the user has to register their own implementation dynamically at runtime. There really isn't an in-between on this.  C++ is not as flexible as Java on this.

Comment: Thanks for the help. In this particular case i will just leave it like it is, but now I understand much better what a factory could be used for.